# Faster way to merge multiple files with unequal number of rows by column in bash

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, paste, merge-file

I have a multiple files that I want to merge by column using shell script, let's say file **a.txt** and file **b.txt**. File **a.txt** contains sorted unique value and the first column will be used as a reference value. 
example :

```
# cat a.txt 
001|johan
002|mike
003|adam
```

```
# cat b.txt
001|chu
001|stewart
002|lewis
002|jordan
003|lambert
003|johnson
003|smith
003|long
```

The both files will be combined to produce an output like below.

```
# cat c.txt
001|johan chu
001|johan stewart
002|mike lewis
002|mike jordan
003|adam lambert
003|adam johnson
003|adam smith
003|adam long
```

I tried simple iteration using `while do`.

```
while read line
do
  ids=`echo $line | awk -F"|" '{print $1}'`
  fn=`grep $ids a.txt`
  echo $fn"|"$line | awk -F"|" '{print $1"|"$2" "$4}'
done < b.txt > c.txt
```

But it takes a lot of time if I have million number of rows.
In `MySQL` we can easily achieve it using `JOIN` clause. But we need to load/insert them first.
Faster approach is probably using `paste` command, but as far as I know, the total rows of both files must be equal. Well I can adjust **a.txt** first. But still comsumes a lot of time when the script running.
Maybe someone has a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all in one `awk` script:

```sh
awk -F'|' '{if (NR==FNR) a[$1]=$2; else print $1 "|" a[$1] " " $2}' a.txt b.txt
```

```
001|johan chu
001|johan stewart
002|mike lewis
002|mike jordan
003|adam lambert
003|adam johnson
003|adam smith
003|adam long
```

Comment: I didn't know `awk` could do such a thing. Splendid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- both files are sorted by the 1st column
- ignore rows that do not have a match in the opposite file

One idea using `join` and `sed` (to remove the 2nd `|`):

```
join -t'|' -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 a.txt b.txt | sed -E 's/\|([^|]*$)/ \1/'
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="|" }
FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next }
$1 in a { print $1,a[$1] " " $2 }
' a.txt b.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
001|johan chu
001|johan stewart
002|mike lewis
002|mike jordan
003|adam lambert
003|adam johnson
003|adam smith
003|adam long
```